# Use node title as page title in views full node page display

Tags: views, 7

I'm using views to link a menu-item to the last node added of a certain content-type.

To accomplish this, I've set up a view to display a 1 full node sorted by post date.

this all works just fine, but now I want to use the node title as page title () instead of the view page title. I also don't want the node title to link to the node again.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to pull this off by writing a small module using following code:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  // Get my view
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME') {
    //get the title of the node shown in the view
    $nid = $vars['view']->result[0]->nid;
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $my_title = $node->title;

    /* Code to dynamically set title here...
       Override view's title since drupal_set_title() is not working.*/
    $vars['view']->build_info['title'] = $my_title;
  }
}
```

This module changes te views page title and uses the nodes title as page title instead.

Now you can remove the linked nodetitle in the node--YOURTYPE.tpl.php

Comment: @Alex Will do so, but is says that I have to wait 1 more day.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great way if you want to address all displays of a view, but what if you want this only for one specific display?

I found an answer to this on http://dropbucket.org/node/194.

```
// first implement hook_preprocess_views_view() which is called for each view.
function HOOK_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['view']->name)) {
    $function = 'HOOK_preprocess_views_view__'.$variables['view']->name; 
    if (function_exists($function)) {
     $function($variables);
    }
  }
}

function HOOK_preprocess_views_view__MY_VIEW_NAME(&$variables) {
  //alter here that specific view
  if($variables['display_id'] == 'page_1') {
  // here it will alter specific display of that view.
    //get the title of the node shown in the view
    $nid = $variables['view']->result[0]->nid;
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $my_title = $node->title;

    /* Code to dynamically set title here...
       Override view's title since drupal_set_title() is not working.*/
    $variables['view']->build_info['title'] = $my_title;
  }
}
```

Now only the page_1 display of a view gets it’s title from the node. All other displays just get the title defined in the display.

Comment: thx for your addition